# Is there a way to change the default font style of SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, font

Anyone had any luck changing the default font style used in Sharepoint online? I am looking for a way to change the styling of the font to Arial but can't find any way of doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the **[react-application-injectcss SPFx web part](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)** to realize your design. Here is **[an article](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/09/sharepoint-online-inject-custom-css-to-modern-sites.html)** to help you bulid react-application-injectcss SPFx.

This is possible using SharePoint Framework extensions application customizer, where you can inject a CSS to your page.

Now, you can override the CSS classes used in your SharePoint online modern pages.

For example:

```
body,div,span,a{
  font-family: cursive !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes that you are using the SharePoint Modern UX.

Use site designs.  [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview)

Also check out the [SharePoint Look Book](https://lookbook.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0):

We used the (PnP - SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection) to override the font styles.  Unfortunately it was not as easy as updating a single line of the stylesheet.  We started basic and then whenever we discovered an area where the font was not applied we inspected the page and found the style we needed to override again.
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/main/samples/react-application-injectcss/README.md